1JMETER - Crear una petición que crezca de forma exponencial para generar Stress
Hola chic@s buen dia para todos, soy un nuevo en esto de las pruebas (QA). Estoy necesitando crear una prueba en Jmeter en donde pueda ir incrementando las peticiones de forma exponencial (por ejemplo que comience con 4 y en 3 minuts termine en 100 por segundo) para crear un stress maximo a un microservicio de Usuarios.
Lo he venido haciendo por medio de varios thread groups pero quisiera saber si hay manera de usar un controlador lógico u alguna otra forma que sea mas sencillo.
De antemano muchas gracias !

Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, te sugerimos revisar [ask], saludos.
